# import js package not working inside another import js file in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

i am using webpack js bundle for my project.I have published a npm module and which included in my webpack entry file.i can access it inside entry file.But that file i can not access inside another file which included in entry file in webpack.Here is my entry file

```
import myClass from  "sbkkoovery-esign";
 console.log(myClass);
import "jquery";
import 'bootstrap';
import "./js/app";
```

here 'myClass' is working properly.But i tried to access 'myClass' inside '/js/app' file.But i am getting error.Here is mu 'js/app' file

```
console.log("here");
console.log(myClass);
```

Comment: Try importing myClass in js file as well

Comment: if i import js file...it will work...is this the coreect method???

Comment: here i import jquery in entry file...but i can access it all the imported files...same way can i do this

Comment: Not sure but only if you define the variable you will be able to access it

Comment: `jquery` might be injecting something to global scope and that is a wrong way to do it. The correct way is to import stuff wherever it is needed. You can import the same file in any number of files. webpack bundler will make sure it comes only once in the final bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue few days back, In this case, rather then to use any node-plugin I have directly given "javascriptfilename.min.js" file path inside  tags in "index.html".
Note: This is not the correct solution, this is just temporary.

Comment: Better post it as a comment

Comment: Yeahh Shubh, i know that, i can write it as a comment but i have recently joined stackoverflow, so as per their policy i need to earned at least 50 reputation points to add any comment. Thanks in advance.